# CMAKE changing Visual Studio Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake

I've been using CMAKE recently on Linux and Windows and I really like it.  Its a great way of spinning up a project and organizing your builds.  There are just a few things that are bugging me and I'm hoping to get help here.

### Visual Studio Settings

Everytime CMAKE generates a project it will be a fresh solution and will not maintain any of the settings you applied to the Visual Studio project.  I know that many things such as CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, etc can change the properties.  But what if I want to change settings such as  "Suppress Startup Banner", "Environment", Enabling Microsoft Symbol Server, Enabling Native Code Debugging.  How do I force CMAKE to set the options I want for fields like these?

### Combining Debug/Release/Etc into one solution

It seems that with CMAKE you have to do separate generations for Debug/Release/etc.  But in typical manually created Visual Studio projects you can combine the profiles and just change a project setting to get your new settings.  Is it possible to generate a single solution file from CMAKE?

Comment: `It seems that with CMAKE you have to do separate generations for Debug/Release/etc.` Are you using nmake files? What you are describing is not my experience. I mean all of my Visual Studio sln files have Debug, Release and RelwithDebInfo configurations and I can use any of these when I want.

Comment: I do however never install vtk, itk, gdcm ... using the CMake INSTALL target since for these libraries there is no naming difference between the Debug and Release libraries/dlls which would limit you to 1 configuration at a time since you can not safely use a Debug dll in a release application or Release dll in a debug application. The reason for this is this will create more than 1 independent heap which can lead to random looking crashes in allocations / deallocations.

Comment: `Visual Studio Settings` There is a possibly of using cmake commands to generate .user files which is where Visual Studio stores these type of settings.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I scoured the CMAKE boards as well.  Here are the answers I found.

### Visual Studio Settings

For this one CMAKE can't modify the *.user files at all.  However what was proposed was to make a user file template and then use CMAKE to supply all the paths and such that you are concerned with.  This worked very well for me.

### Combining Debug/Release/Etc into one solution

To change various settings on a per configuration basis.  It seems like it is best to use fields like CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_ and most importantly generator expressions.  Generator expressions allow you to test for the build type and then generate whatever include, libraries, etc that you need.

Take a look at "Generator Expressions" [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_include_directories)